# Subject.forkJoin is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm getting this error "**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_Rx**.Subject.forkJoin is not a function" when using forkJoin on a subject, any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

uploadImages(imgsToUpload: File[]): Subject<void> {
    let subjImgs: Subject<void>[] = [];
    let subj: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    if (imgsToUpload && imgsToUpload.length > 0) {
      imgsToUpload.forEach(img => {
        subjImgs.push(this.mediaResourceService.uploadFile(img));
      });
      Subject.forkJoin(subjImgs).subscribe(x => subj.next());
    } else {
      subj.next();
    }
    return subj;
  }
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `forkJoin()` on a `Subject` because `forkJoin` returns an Observable anyway. Did you add it with `import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'`?

Comment: I've tried both imports, still get the error, I get the forkJoin method on visual studio suggestions so everything should be fine.
Is there another way you think I could implement this method ?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried just `Observable.forkJoin()`?

Comment: Like a charm, thanks mate.
So I'm working on the code of a colleague and am bit new to angular and rxjs, so, pardon me.